# Codeigniter pagination using semantic UI

Tags: codeigniter, pagination, semantic-ui

I use bellow code for pagination:

```
    $config['full_tag_open'] = "<div class='ui right floated pagination menu'>";
    $config['full_tag_close'] ="</div>";
    $config['num_tag_open'] = '<a class="item">';
    $config['num_tag_close'] = '</a>';
    $config['cur_tag_open'] = '<a class="item">';
    $config['cur_tag_close'] = "</a>";
    $config['next_tag_open'] = '<a class="item">';
    $config['next_tagl_close'] = "</a>";
    $config['prev_tag_open'] = '<a class="item">';
    $config['prev_tagl_close'] = "</a>";
    $config['first_tag_open'] = '<a class="item">';
    $config['first_tagl_close'] = "</a>";
    $config['last_tag_open'] = '<a class="item">';
    $config['last_tagl_close'] = "</a>";
```

Not working the design part. How to use correctly using semantic ui

Comment: what you mean by semantic UI ??

Comment: CSS framework like bootstrap

Comment: so where is you `$config` settings ??

Comment: http://pastebin.com/TBbtgHvs

Comment: Not working measn what?? can you clear bit more??

Comment: semantic ui pagination design is not working

Comment: style not calling in view ??

Comment: For styling I use question part in config. Still not working

Comment: answer added. Check it out

Answer (score 0):

create a a file name pagination.php in config

and call it from controller or model

```
include APPPATH.'config/pagination.php';
```

when your going to pass this config file and below is the full code:

```
$config = array();
        $config["base_url"] = base_url() . 'brands/index';
        $config["total_rows"] = $this->brand->brand_count();

        include APPPATH.'config/pagination.php';
        $this->pagination->initialize($config);

        $page = ($this->uri->segment(3)) ? $this->uri->segment(3) : 0;
        $data["results"] = $this->brand->
            get_brands($config["per_page"], $page);
        $data["links"] = $this->pagination->create_links();

                $this->load->view('brand/view',$data);
```

Comment: Only design part problem bro

Comment: oh okay so you want to display the design then call in the view <?php echo $links;?>

Comment: does the css file and js declared properly

Comment: <div class="ui pagination menu">
  <a class="item">
    1
  </a>
  <div class="disabled item">
    ...
  </div>
  <a class="item active">
    10
  </a>
  <a class="item">
    11
  </a>
  <a class="item">
    12
  </a>
</div>

Comment: Sorry bro. U didnt get my ques. This code mess with codeigniter pagination

Comment: i know but when i try the code when i open the first numbers are okay but when i go to next page it broke

Comment: try this page bro http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23032561/error-pagination-in-codeigniter

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$config['full_tag_open'] = '<div class="ui pagination menu">';
$config['full_tag_close'] ='</div>';
$config['num_tag_open'] = '<a class="item">';
$config['num_tag_close'] = '</a>';
$config['cur_tag_open'] = '<a class="active item">';
$config['cur_tag_close'] = '</a>';
$config['next_tag_open'] = '<a class="item">';
$config['next_tagl_close'] = '</a>';
$config['prev_tag_open'] = '<a class="item">';
$config['prev_tagl_close'] = '</a>';
$config['first_tag_open'] = '<a class="item">';
$config['first_tagl_close'] = '</a>';
$config['last_tag_open'] = '<a class="item">';
$config['last_tagl_close'] = '</a>';
```

[Semantic UI Pagination Stayles](http://semantic-ui.com/collections/menu.html#pagination)

Answer (score 0):

Here is my working code for Bootstrap v4.0 and Codeigniter v3

```
$config['full_tag_open'] = '<ul class="pagination">';
$config['full_tag_close'] ='</ul>';
$config['num_tag_open'] = '<li class="page-item">';
$config['num_tag_close'] = '</li>';
$config['cur_tag_open'] = '<li class="page-item active"><a class="page-link" href="#">';
$config['cur_tag_close'] = '</a></li>';
$config['next_tag_open'] = '<li class="page-item"><a href="#" aria-label="Next">';
$config['next_tagl_close'] = '</a></li>';
$config['prev_tag_open'] = '<li class="page-item">';
$config['prev_tagl_close'] = '</li>';
$config['first_tag_open'] = '<li class="page-item disabled">';
$config['first_tagl_close'] = '</li>';
$config['last_tag_open'] = '<li class="page-item"><a href="#" aria-label="Next">';
$config['last_tagl_close'] = '</a></li>';
$config['attributes'] = array('class' => 'page-link');
```